# urlmappings changes - grails 2 to 3 upgrade

Tags: grails

I have the following mapping in my `UrlMappings.groovy`:

`"/$controller/$action?/$id?/$id2?/$id3?" {constraints {}}`

Given a request url   `xcontroller/xaction/xid1//xid3`  ( note `//` )

grails 2.x would produce values for id and id3 but not id2.  this is what i would have expected.

In grails 3.2.5, this url only produces id1 and id2 values ( xid3 becomes id2 ).  It appears the `//` is ignored.

Have others experienced this issue?  Is it a bug or desired change?

Comment: Check the "dynamically resolved variables" section in http://docs.grails.org/3.1.1/guide/single.html#urlmappings. It might help setting a default value for missing tokens...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I consider the old behavior a bug and the new behavior as preferred. Empty path segements like `//` should get resolved to nothing, and further all of the following URLs should be equivalent:

```
http://host/foo/bar
http://host/foo//bar
http://host/foo/./bar
```

[RFC3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) discusses URI syntax.

You could use a dummy value like `0` as a placeholder for "missing" components.